# How to boot from cd

Tags: windows-7, boot, operating-systems, iso-image

I've recently bought a hp pavillion 15 n228sl, with Windows 8.

I decided to install Windows 7 on it; so, to make a clean install and get rid of all those partition, I downloaded killdisk at this page (http://www.killdisk.com/downloadfree.htm, at the very bottom; "bootable ISO image for DOS").

To burn it onto a CD (I have a MAC at home), I opened the ISO file with disk utility, converted it to master CD/DVD, and burned that file image to a CD-RW, again with disk utility

The problem is that, when I insert it in the new pc and restart, nothing happens, and it goes straight to the windows boot screen.

I already modified the BIOS preference so that the system tries to boot from CD first, and I also enabled the legacy system (that to my understanding allows "old" disk images to be recognized, such as Windows 7 image), but with no use.

I have no idea what the problem might be!

Comment: Have you verified the CD actually works? If the system has been correctly told to check the CD drive for bootable media first, and it's not seeing anything bootable in that CD drive, then I'd suspect the disk.

Comment: @music2myear well when windows boots up I can see that the cd actually contains some files. I have no idea if they are what they are supposed to be, but something is there for sure.

Comment: If you actually have the BIOS set up correctly to try to boot to CD before trying to boot from HDD, the CD drive will spin up after the BIOS is done and before starting Windows - no matter if the cd is bootable or not. This is easy to hear. Does it spin up?

Comment: @Peter I am sure the BIOS is set up correctly, because when I inserted the windows 7 dvd it booted correctly, giving me the opportunity to install windows 7. I don't know if it spins when I insert the other cd, but I guess so :)

Comment: What version of windows 8 did it come with?

Comment: @Vdub Honestly I am not sure. I installed windows 7 in the meantime, but on second thought I decided to make a clean install, getting rid of the other partitions. So now I have windows 7 on the pc

Comment: The reason I ask is because downgrading from windows 8 has been a tricky situation. If it came with windows 8 pro you can downgrade if its standard you cant. Im not completely sure what blocks it but I do remember trying to downgrade from standard to 7 pro and it blocked me in start up and I believe it was at the same section of booting from cd/dvd. Try reading this < http://www.pcworld.com/article/2015107/downgrading-from-windows-8-to-7-what-you-need-to-know.html >

Comment: @Vdub the link is dead. But I am not trying to downgrade, I want to wipe everything and then install windows 7. Would it prevent me from installing Ubuntu, for example?

Comment: Sorry fixed the link :) I'm not sure. I don't want to use windows 8 in my work environment with 80+ users, it would be a headache, I am planning on waiting until windows 9 to upgrade everyone and start teaching users the new OS. Sorry I couldn't be more help, after seeing the headache of downgrading I gave up lol I don't have that much time.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your answers to the comments above I am going to guess the issue is with your CD. In order to boot, a specific bit needs to be set in the CD data itself which informs the system the CD can be booted from and telling it what to load. This is separate from the data on the CD itself, so you could have a CD that you can see data on, but unless that "bootable bit" is set correctly, the system will not being loading information from the disk during boot.

Please re-check the instructions for creating a bootable CD. If possible, use a Windows computer to do this, as there may be settings in the Apple computer which make creating a disk a Windows computer recognizes as bootable impossible.

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: Please provide a constructive comment when downvoting.

Comment: I just tried to do that, but with no results. I burned the ISO file from within the killdisk program, and even if it said that is was okay, when I restarted the pc it did not work. What to do now?

Comment: I see that Killdisk offers a Windows suite that can create the bootable disk itself. Have you tried this?

Personally, I have used Darik's Boot and Nuke and found it works well enough, but I do not believe it has the bootable disk creator program Killdisk offers.

Are you certain you are burning to a CD, or might you have burned to a DVD?

Comment: Yes I used the utility to create the bootable disc. Now I am trying DBAN, and also trying a different Cd. Maybe this CD-RW is not working properly

Comment: Oh, you're not closing the disk after the burn? AFAIK, you have to close the disk (make it no longer re-writable) if you want to boot from it.

Answer (score 1):

Time out.  Why do you need killdisk?  **If you want to install Windows cleanly, you do not need to do any disk erasing nor partition removing with a third-party utility.  Windows can do it for you.**  Just boot the Windows install CD, and when it gets to the part where it asks what partition to install on, you can change the partitions (and remove existing ones to start completely clean).

Look at this page for the screens involved.  Notice they choose the "Custom" install option to get to the screens where it asks about partitions.
http://archive.benchmarkreviews.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=399&Itemid=38&limitstart=3

I recommend you just delete all the existing ones, then create a new one, letting it use all available space.  It will then (in my experience) create a very small boot partition in addition.  And you're all set.  I'm pretty sure it gives you the option to actually format the partitions, if you want to make double sure the data is cleaned off (and verify the disk's surface is all usable).

Comment: There have been issues reported with OEM-built Windows 8 partitions not going away correctly in the standard windows install process, possibly related to some of the security in the UEFI system.